# "Reverse for 'about' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$about$'] Request Method:"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

Following error occurs on runserver command:
    In template C:\Users\V\Downloads\DJANGO\blog_project\mysite\blog\templates\blog\base.html, error at line 26

```
Line 26 in base.html is:
   <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>

In App's URL file:
    url(r'^about', views.AboutView.as_view(), name='about')
    path('about',views.AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
Tried both with and without $ sign.

And in views.py file 
    class AboutView(TemplateView):
        template_name = 'about.html'
```

Below are app as we as project file urls'
    App URL file:
    from django.urls import path
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    url(r'^about', views.AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
    #path('about/',views.AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^post/new/$', views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', views.PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_edit'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$', views.PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post_remove'),
    url(r'^drafts/$', views.DraftListView.as_view(), name='post_draft_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/comment/$', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),
    url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/approve/$', views.comment_approve, name='comment_approve'),
    url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', views.comment_remove, name='comment_remove'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/publish/$', views.post_publish, name='post_publish'),
```

]

```
project URL (mysite)

from django.contrib import admin
# from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'$', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/login/', views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout', kwargs={'next_page': '/'}),
```

]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the patterns as shown below: For old versions of django use the first.

```
url(r'^about/$', views.AboutView.as_view(), name='about')
path('about/', views.AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
```

Comment: url(r'$', include('blog.urls')), change it to url(r'^', include('blog.urls')), and add slash on about url as shown

Comment: url(r'^', include('blog.urls')) worked for me. Thanks a lot